# Eclipse IDE Java compiling issues

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to use Eclipse IDE for Java coding. I am trying to run the code from the following site:

https://gitlab.inria.fr/structgraphics/code/

It returns with the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class Chan\git\code\target\classes;C:\Users\Samson
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Chan\git\code\target\classes;C:\Users\Samson

Also I note that there is a small red-x appeared in the src sections as attached image shows:

[Red-x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxF5g.png)

Problem tab shows the following:

[Problem Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkBSi.png)

Grateful if I can have your help to solve this issues. Thank you very much.

Comment: check the "Problems" view for the full error message of that red-x (or hover the mouse over the rror to get its message) add that to the question, should help narrow down the problem (could be wrong Java version) - I won't test it "No license. All rights reserved"

Comment: Thanks and here is the message showed in the problems tag....Preview features enabled at an invalid source release level 14, preview can be enabled only at source level 15
Preview features enabled at an invalid source release level 14, preview can be enabled only at source level 15

Comment: Open up module-info.java and show us its content please

Comment: 'Project Properties - Java Compiler' or global properties 'Window - Preferences - Java - Compiler': uncheck "Enable preview features"; **or** change "Compiler compliance level" to 15 (eventually change execution environment to 15) ((desperate mode, use an older eclipse that allows preview features for Java 14, e.g. 2020-06))

Answer (score 0):

issue is your project is not compiled properly, ideally there already maven support.
If your configured [maven](https://www.toolsqa.com/java/maven/how-to-install-maven-eclipse-ide/) properly refresh the project it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know what do you mean by configured maven? How it can be done in Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Check here https://www.toolsqa.com/java/maven/how-to-install-maven-eclipse-ide/